# Нужна функция которая сможет сделать экземпляр класса недостижимым

Tags: c#, .net, c#-7.3

Есть код. Надо передать методу экземпляр класса, а он должн сделать его недостижимым.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Cat cat1 = new Cat();
            Cat cat2 = new Cat();

            Program.CatNullifier(cat1);
            Program.CatNullifier(cat2);

            Console.WriteLine(cat1);
            Console.WriteLine(cat1 == null);
            Console.WriteLine(cat2);
            Console.WriteLine(cat2 == null);
        }
        public static  void CatNullifier(Cat cat)
        {

        }

    }

    public class Cat {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В каком смысле "сделать недостижимым"? Судя по названиям в коде - видимо, нужно присвоить в функции `null` переменной с экземпляром, в этом случае можно использовать передачу в функцию ссылки на переменную через `ref`, насколько я ещё помню `C#`, и присвоить этой переменной `null`:

```cs
public static void CatNullifier(ref Cat cat)
{
    cat = null;
}
```

Возможно, нужно ещё и `out` использовать кроме `ref`, но я уже точно не помню.